# dd not making usb bootable

Tags: dd, bootable

I'm trying to create a centos 7 install usb but for some reason dd does not make the usb bootable. I've used the following:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
fd0      2:0    1     4K  0 disk 
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 160.9G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0  90.5G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0    39G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1     0B  0 disk 
sdc      8:32   1     0B  0 disk 
sdd      8:48   1     0B  0 disk 
sde      8:64   1     0B  0 disk 
sdf      8:80   1  29.3G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I'm trying to put it on sdf and it's not mounted. I'm using the command

```
$ sudo dd bs=4M if=/home/user/Desktop/CentOS-7-i386-Everything-2009.iso of=/dev/sdf conv=fdatasync  status=progress
8287944704 bytes (8.3 GB, 7.7 GiB) copied, 1027 s, 8.1 MB/s
1976+1 records in
1976+1 records out
8291639296 bytes (8.3 GB, 7.7 GiB) copied, 1125.72 s, 7.4 MB/s
```

I'm really stumped. I've successfully created and booted from a usb made with this method on the same PC a lot of times. I don't get it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After replugging the stick, `cmp file.iso /dev/stick` says EOF on file.iso? Checksum of file.iso itself is correct? file.iso is meant for USB sticks? dd just writes data, so it depends on how the iso itself was made. you can use `wipefs -a` on the stick to remove old partition headers (GPT backup at end of disk)

Comment: output `cmp: EOF on /home/kali/Desktop/CentOS-7-i386-Everything-2009.iso after byte 8291639296, in line 32820404` . The iso is from the official site and they claim it to be usable on usb sticks. I've tried the wipefs -a and dd again and will try to boot from it now.

Comment: Do you really need the i386 image rather than the x86_64 one? Similarly, CentOS 7 rather than 8...?

Comment: I'm messing with an old machine so...it probably could handle those, but this just seems more appropriate i guess

Comment: 1. Please verify that the checksum of the iso file is correct. 2. Please test with some other (I suggest smaller) Linux iso file, that the computer can boot when cloned from the USB stick.

Comment: `dd` doesn't make anything bootable.  It just copies data from the source to the target.  If you copied an ISO image file to a USB stick and it wouldn't boot, then the problem is in either the ISO file or the USB stick.   Test that by trying a different ISO file and/or a different USB stick.